# 1 hour discrepancy between created_date field in MySQL and CiviCRM report output

Tags: drupal, civireport, mysql, timezone

I hope I have a strange, but straight forward issue -- there's a 1 hour offset SOMETIMES in the created_date field in civicrm_contact table, and what gets outputted in a CiviCRM report (see the attached images).

MySQL is set to use SYSTEM time as well as PHP - ie, and no timezone conflict.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. We are using Drupal 7 + CiviCRM 4.6.

[image: Time in MYSQL]

[image: Time in Detailed Member Report]

Comment: what is your users timezone setting in drupal?

Comment: It's strange, both were set to Eastern (-4). However, when I switched my timezone to UTC (0) in Drupal, the timestamps were displayed as expected, but now we have that PHP/MySQL timestamp mismatch warning. I also noticed the created_date is set as "TIMESTAMP" in the database, but the format is clearly DATETIME -- is there a reason for this?

Comment: really not sure sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same version (4.6.7), this was the fix for our issue - Drupal timezone code does not handle UTC correctly - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6576

Answer (score 1):

It's a timezone issue. Your database and drupal timezone must be same. Sometime it's happen due to Daylight saving time.